# Google Chrome doesn't respond user actions correctly

Tags: linux, google-chrome, kde

Recently I've changed my OS to **Ubuntu 12.04 (Cinnamon, 64 bits)** from Mint 13 (KDE, 64 bits) and one same bug still appears on new installation.

The Google Chrome it seems that don't refresh (repaint) page based on my interactions. Example:

When i'm try comment an Youtube vídeo, when i click on textarea, o cursor don't appear inside of textarea, BUT, when/if i change to another tab and return the cursor appears...OK...
If i start write some text...according i'm typing the chars don't appers...again if i change to another tab and return the typed text appears on textarea.

Other cases that this bug appears:

- Modal boxes link...don't show the modal;
- Forms inside modal boxes don't show typed chars;
- The common Discus comment plugin don't work when focused;

I don't have any idea of reason of this bug. (video driver, window manager, Chrome bug ?, i don't know)

Any idea to solve this ?

Additional informations:

```
Google Chrome   22.0.1229.79 (Official Build 158531)
OS  Linux
WebKit  537.4 (@129177)
JavaScript  V8 3.12.19.11
Flash   11.3.31.331
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Command Line     /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path    /home/carlos/.config/google-chrome/Default

Kernel version: 3.2.0-31-generic-pae Ubuntu 12.04
```

Best regards.

Comment: How so ? Can caused by classic video/interface bugs with Window managers on Linux..maybe :/

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your qt GTK theme.
What theme are teu using?

Comment: Try to reinstall it, with the latest version. It should work quite right now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this case was reinstall to Kubuntu 12.04. All cases mentioned on this answer has been solved.

I've believe that Cinnamon it's the reason of this video bugs.